a 5 by 5 zero-one matrix with determinant 5
I am looking for a python code to create a 5 by 5 zero-one matrix with determinant equal to 5. (Such a matrix does exist but it is a consequence of some mathematical theorems. I like to try to find an actual example of such matrix using computer)
Creating a simple search code is time consuming (at least for my little pc!) because there are 2^(25) 5 by 5 zero-one matrix.

Consider utilizing a hill-climbing approach:
import numpy as np


def generate_initial_matrix(size: int = 5) -> np.ndarray:
  """Generates an initial random matrix with elements 0 or 1.
  Args:
    size: The size of the matrix to generate. Defaults to 5.
  Returns:
    A size x size numpy array with random 0 or 1 entries.
  """
  return np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(size, size))


def tweak_matrix(matrix: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
  """Randomly tweaks a single element in the matrix.
  Args:
    matrix: The matrix to be tweaked.
  Returns:
    A new matrix with one element flipped (0 to 1 or 1 to 0).
  """
  i, j = np.random.randint(0, matrix.shape[0], 2)
  matrix[i, j] = 1 - matrix[i, j]  # Flip between 0 and 1
  return matrix


def find_matrix_with_determinant(
    target_det: int = 5,
    size: int = 5,
    max_attempts: int = 10000,
) -> np.ndarray | None:
  """Trys to find a size x size zero-one matrix with a target determinant.
  Args:
    target_det: The target determinant. Defaults to 5.
    size: The size of the matrix. Defaults to 5.
    max_attempts: The maximum number of attempts. Defaults to 10000.
  Returns:
    A size x size np.ndarray with the target determinant or None if not found.
  """
  matrix = generate_initial_matrix(size)
  best_det = np.linalg.det(matrix)
  for _ in range(max_attempts):
    if int(best_det) == target_det:
      return matrix
    new_matrix = tweak_matrix(matrix.copy())
    new_det = np.linalg.det(new_matrix)
    new_matrix_closer = abs(new_det - target_det) < abs(best_det - target_det)
    accept_worse_solution_to_escape_local_minima = np.random.rand() < 0.01
    if new_matrix_closer or accept_worse_solution_to_escape_local_minima:
      matrix, best_det = new_matrix, new_det
  return None


def main() -> None:
  target_det = 5
  size = 5
  max_attempts = 10000
  result_matrix = find_matrix_with_determinant(target_det,
                                               size=size,
                                               max_attempts=max_attempts)
  if result_matrix is not None:
    print(f'Found a matrix of size {size} x {size} with determinant {target_det}:\n', result_matrix)
  else:
    print(f'No matrix size {size} x {size} found with {target_det=} within {max_attempts=}.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

Example output matrix_size = 5:
Found a matrix of size 5 x 5 with determinant 5:
 [[0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]]

Example output with matrix_size = 20:
Found a matrix of size 20 x 20 with determinant 5:
 [[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]]


Thank you very much. I learned so much from your code. This works well for dimension 5 or larger matrices such as 10 by 10. But when I try to run it for 20 by 20 matrices I get no answer. Is there a way or algorithm that I can use to handle 20 by 20 cases??
Also would you please explain me the role of  "accept_worse_solution_to_escape_local_minima" and why we need that ??

20 x 20 works see above., For accept_worse_solution_to_escape_local_minima explanation, basically, the algorithm sometimes accepts a worse solution with a certain probability. This allows the search to jump out of the local minima and explore other parts of the search space, potentially finding a better global solution.

For 20 by 20 case I am looking for a matrix with determinant equal to 56640625. (such a matrix exists)
